# Hardcoding values in Java

Tags: java, testing, defaultmutabletreenode

Currently I'm trying to Hardcode some values for a family tree application in Java.

Just need some ideas on how to go about it, not sure how to proceed.

I have also included the constructor classes:

```
  public class TreeImpl {

    private FamilyMember root;

    public FamilyMember getRoot() {
        return root;
    }

    public void setRoot(FamilyMember root) {
        this.root = root;
    }

    public List<FamilyMember> getAllMembers() {
        return allMembers;
    }

    public void setAllMembers(List<FamilyMember> allMembers) {
        this.allMembers = allMembers;
        this.setRoot(this.allMembers.get(0));
    }

    private List<FamilyMember> allMembers = new ArrayList<>();

    public TreeImpl(FamilyMember root)
    {
        this.root=root;
        addMembers(root);
    }

    private void addMembers(FamilyMember node)
    {
        if(node==null) return;
        allMembers.add(node);
        addMembers(node.getFather());
        addMembers(node.getMother());
        addMembers(node.getSpouse());


        for(FamilyMember child : node.getChildren())
            addMembers(child);

    }

    public void addSpouse(int index, FamilyMember spouse)
    {
        for(FamilyMember member : allMembers)
        {
            if(member.getMemberID()==index)
            {
                member.setSpouse(spouse);
                allMembers.add(spouse);
                return;
            }
        }
    }

    public void addFather(int index, FamilyMember father)
    {
        for(FamilyMember member : allMembers)
        {
            if(member.getMemberID()==index)
            {
                member.setFather(father);
                allMembers.add(father);
                return;
            }
        }
    }

    public void addMother(int index, FamilyMember mother)
    {
        for(FamilyMember member : allMembers)
        {
            if(member.getMemberID()==index)
            {
                member.setMother(mother);
                allMembers.add(mother);
                return;
            }
        }
    }

    public void addChild(int index, FamilyMember child)
    {
        for(FamilyMember member : allMembers)
        {
            if(member.getMemberID()==index)
            {
                member.setSpouse(child);
                allMembers.add(child);
                return;
            }
        }
    }



    public FamilyMember getDetailsForMember(String member)
    {

        for(FamilyMember m : this.getAllMembers())
        {
            if(m.getFirstName().equals(member))
                return m;
        }

        return null;
    }
```

My constructor class

```
public class FamilyMember implements Serializable{
    private static int id=1;

    private String firstName, surName, surNameAfterMarriage, life;
    private Gender gender;
    private Address address;
    private FamilyMember mother, father, spouse;
    private int memberID;

    public boolean hasSub()
    {
        return (this.getFather()!=null || this.getMother()!=null || this.getChildren().size()>0);
    }


    public int getMemberID() {
        return memberID;
    }

    public void setMemberID(int memberID) {
        this.memberID = memberID;
    }

    private List<FamilyMember> children, grandChildren;

    public static int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public static void incrementId()
    {
        id++;
    }


    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getSurName() {
        return surName;
    }

    public void setSurName(String surName) {
        this.surName = surName;
    }

    public String getSurNameAfterMarriage() {
        return surNameAfterMarriage;
    }

    public void setSurNameAfterMarriage(String surNameAfterMarriage) {
        this.surNameAfterMarriage = surNameAfterMarriage;
    }

    public String getLife() {
        return life;
    }

    public void setLife(String life) {
        this.life = life;
    }

    public Gender getGender() {
        return gender;
    }

    public void setGender(Gender gender) {
        this.gender = gender;
    }

    public Address getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(Address address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public FamilyMember getMother() {
        return mother;
    }

    public void setMother(FamilyMember mother) {
        this.mother = mother;
    }

    public FamilyMember getFather() {
        return father;
    }

    public void setFather(FamilyMember father) {
        this.father = father;
    }

    public FamilyMember(String firstName, String surName, String surNameAfterMarriage, String life, Gender gender,
            Address address) {
        super();
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.surName = surName;
        this.surNameAfterMarriage = surNameAfterMarriage;
        this.life = life;
        this.gender = gender;
        this.address = address;
        this.memberID = this.getId();
        this.children = new ArrayList<>();
        this.incrementId();
    }


        for(FamilyMember child : this.getChildren())
        {
            text = text + " " + child.firstName;
        }

        return text;
    }

    public FamilyMember getSpouse() {
        return spouse;
    }

    public void setSpouse(FamilyMember spouse) {
        this.spouse = spouse;
    }

    public List<FamilyMember> getChildren() {
        return children;
    }

    public void setChildren(List<FamilyMember> childer) {
        this.children = childer;
    }

    public void addChild(FamilyMember child) {
        this.children.add(child);
    }


    public List<FamilyMember> getGrandChildren() {
        return grandChildren;
    }

    public void setGrandChildren(List<FamilyMember> grandChildren) {
        this.grandChildren = grandChildren;
    }


}
```

For examples, I want to add details for father, mothers, child etc so when I run the program, these values are displayed

Eg: `Familymember father = new Familymember ("xyz". "xyx" )`

Comment: so whats ur doubt?

Comment: I am not sure how to hardcode the values. Any ideas? 

Where do I add it?

Comment: You mean how to handle "xyz" ?

Comment: How about loading it from file? Maybe from xml or something similar. This way, you would see your tree outside of the application and you woudn't need to touch your code to change it.

Comment: Yep. I want to create a new constructor with custom values for each family member but how and where do I then add this

Comment: @synth I wish. But I cant do that. It has to be through the program

Comment: I still don't understand your question. What do you want to create? The FamilyTree or the FamilyMember? What values do you want to hardcode?

Answer (score 0):

You can set values using Constructor,

```
public FamilyMember (Gender gen,Address add,FamilyMember fmm,FamilyMember fmf,FamilyMember fms,int mId){
            this.gender = gen;
            this.address = add;
            this.mother = fmm;
            this.father = fmf;
            this.spouse = fms;
            this.memberID = mId;
        }
```

it will set the FamilyMember object with hard coded values,

```
FamilyMember fm = new FamilyMember(Gender.MALE,add,fmm,fmf,fms,menId);
```

Let me know if any quires.

Comment: I can create the constuctor like this :
FamilyMember father = new FamilyMember ("a'', "b", "c", "d");

I understand this, but how do I then insert it in the node?

Comment: hmm, you can create but based on object only u can create. FamilyMember father = new FamilyMember ("a'', "b", "c", "d") it's wont accept this type. u can create constructor based on how u initialize the variables.

Comment: Its hardcoded. But how do I then implement it into the program? Like .add (fm)

Comment: remove hardcoded values and then pass respect object u want to bind thats it

Comment: any sample please :)

Comment: Thats all the info I have atm. I am trying to problem solve with the above code

Answer (score 0):

If you really want it through a constructor, you could do it this way:

```
// Secondary constructor
public FamilyMember() {
    this("Paul", "Stevenson", ...); // calls the primary constructor
}

public FamilyMember(String firstName, String surName, String surNameAfterMarriage, String life, Gender gender,
            Address address) {
    // your primary constructor
}
```

Unfortunately this isn't very flexible. An alternative is to use a static method :

```
public static FamilyMember familyMemberSteve() {
    return new FamilyMember("Steve", ...)
}
```

But to be honest, I wouldn't recommend this either. Like I said in the comment, it would be better to use XML or another format, because it would be more flexible.

Answer (score 0):

Create a a static method in FamilyMember class that creates a family and then call this method before initialising a TreeImpl object.

```
public static FamilyMember createFirstFamilyNode() {
    FamilyMember mother = new FamilyMember("Mother", ...);
    FamilyMember father = new FamilyMember("Father", ...);

    mother.setSpouce(father);
    FamilyMember child1 = new FamilyMember("First Child", ...);
    mother.addChild(child1);

    // And so on for rest of family members

    return mother;
}
```

Comment: I would imagine you called this method when the application firsts load together with the tree.